# Is it possible to define instances of Data.Foldable with foldr where foldr takes arguments of different types?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

The type class [Data.Foldable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) has the following definition:

```
class Foldable t where
    {-# MINIMAL foldMap | foldr #-}
    foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
    foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
    ....
    <more definitions>
```

The minimal stanza says, that I it's possible to define an instance only with the *foldr* function.
In all the examples I can compile, the foldr function has type `a -> a -> a`. However I'm unable 
to define something where the *foldr* function has really type `a -> b -> b` where the types `a` and `b`
are different.

The following code shows an example, that does NOT compile:

```
import Data.Foldable

data Tree a = Tree a a | Leaf a

class Size a where
   size :: a -> Int 

instance Size a => Foldable (Tree a) where
  foldr :: a -> Int -> Int
  foldr x n = size x + n
```

Is it possible to define an instance of Foldable with `foldr`, where the types `a` and `b` are really different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't that the types are different. The type of your `foldr` is just not the same as what `Foldable` requires. It would need to be:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
```

And those `a` and `b` type parameters must remain as parameters: this has to work *for all* choices of `a` and `b`. You can't constrain them to some other type class and you can't restrict one of them to be a concrete `Int` type.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you want can be achieved by using the actual `foldr` function instead of modifying it. You can not change the signature of a type class method, and in this case, there is no need. Try implementing `foldr` by providing a sensible implementation of its type and then write a function `addSize` that can be passed as the first argument to `foldr`. `foldr addSize 0` will have the behavior you want.